# Apollo takes 100% CPU

Tags: activemq-classic, mqtt

I use ActiveMQ Apollo 1.7.1 in Linux.  I use MQTT to send message from server to client.

Apollo config like below:

```xml
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/activemq/apollo">

  <notes>
    The default configuration with tls/ssl enabled.
  </notes>

  <log_category console="console" security="security" connection="connection" audit="audit"/>


  <authentication domain="apollo"/>
  <!-- Give admins full access -->
  <access_rule allow="admins" action="*"/>
  <access_rule allow="*" action="connect" kind="connector"/>


  <virtual_host id="myapollo">
    <host_name>myapollo</host_name>

    <access_rule allow="users" action="connect create destroy send receive consume"/>

    <leveldb_store directory="${apollo.base}/data"/>


  </virtual_host>


  <connector id="tcp" bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:61613"/>

  <key_storage file="${apollo.base}/etc/keystore" password="password" key_password="password"/>

</broker>
```

Can someone tell me how to find information about why the Apollo process is taking 100% of the CPU?
After this problem happens we can't build new connections through TCP.

Comment: @JustinBertram, Yes you are right, I know we should change the solution. 
But at this moment, I have to fix this issue before I have time to change technology. We can't completely stop the push notification function for even a second

Comment: I have an application Android which is a client side. If i cange Apollo to ActiveMQ, do you think I need code to make my application works with ActiveMQ ?

Comment: @JustinBertram, How to get a couple of thread dumps from the JVM ?

Comment: Any update here? Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: yes, the problem is always there but it occurs irregular

Comment: Did you ever get any thread dumps or migrate to another broker?

Comment: I change 2 config : receive_buffer_size = 2048 , JVM_FLAGS = "-server-Xmx2G". After then In these two weeks, this has not happened again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveMQ Apollo has had no releases in almost a decade and the [`readme.md` in the source code](https://github.com/apache/activemq-apollo) indicates the project is dead. Therefore you're unlikely to get much help. My recommendation would be to get a couple of [thread dumps](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump) from the JVM, and then restart the broker. Hopefully things will return to normal, and then you can inspect the thread dumps to investigate the underlying cause of the CPU utilization.

Eventually you should switch to a broker under active development. Personally I'd recommend [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) which has replaced Apollo as the next-generation broker from ActiveMQ. MQTT is a standard protocol so you should be able to deploy any broker which implements MQTT and your clients should still work. For what it's worth, ActiveMQ Artemis recently implemented MQTT 5 so if you think you'll ever upgrade your clients to MQTT 5 you'll have a smooth upgrade path.